# Ktor - Quickstart new project from plugin throwing Error

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, ktor

I am using:

- Kotlin 1.3.3
- Ktor plugin 1.2.0
- IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-191.7479.7, built
  on May 21, 2019
- openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 - OpenJDK Runtime Environment
  18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
- macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Also tried with 'jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/'

I follow the QuickStart from https://ktor.io/quickstart/index.html

When I run the generated code from inside IntelliJ I get:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 EAP.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50192:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 EAP.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/HelloKtorWorld/out/production/classes:/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/HelloKtorWorld/out/production/resources:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-server-netty/1.2.0/c30ea7f287343d3007a0794dbfeb3f69aad76ca8/ktor-server-netty-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-html-builder/1.2.0/53ef376dc21a1f404a5154096708fc104092ec77/ktor-html-builder-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-server-host-common/1.2.0/a4335b06f785b39d976e70a00a988bd077beacd1/ktor-server-host-common-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-server-core/1.2.0/4ba64df7deeb3b3cc81b66f005962edfaf63e554/ktor-server-core-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/kotlin-css-jvm/1.0.0-pre.31-kotlin-1.2.41/718c1d40ec10699ee0ab086e2e9d4d1ebe95646d/kotlin-css-jvm-1.0.0-pre.31-kotlin-1.2.41.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-client-jetty/1.2.0/3dd4fd4541dd7c85564c65162117a2dd60933f0b/ktor-client-jetty-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-client-core-jvm/1.2.0/f88e71cffbb49bdba1f1e93131cdee2e2bae0eaa/ktor-client-core-jvm-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-http-cio-jvm/1.2.0/d37a4df9617f49378780554421a3744ab5ceb1d9/ktor-http-cio-jvm-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-http-jvm/1.2.0/aab3e7e34ba1c1947fe362f899d308d97622cfb8/ktor-http-jvm-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-network/1.2.0/bbaefc8c4d66d3707b0a247a341a2f3ea7bd0c5/ktor-network-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-utils-jvm/1.2.0/9d79aff946644c0f489e75f315fcb396f5b4581e/ktor-utils-jvm-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.31/21edc5a6b2e39bc4dc2860346fd778e27503d6cb/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.31.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.1/706a8b8206ead3683ec639dd270d11fd948fbb0e/logback-classic-1.2.1.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-client-core/1.2.0/5788736ce2795078281e5eeb4523e0c81cf8d06/ktor-client-core-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.31/e652770b6416c6d85934086899ffed3eccd35813/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.31.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.31/5a426a5ada97967ca60fba495eeaa66cfa7c9e2f/kotlin-reflect-1.3.31.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-io-jvm/0.1.8/591b0489ce565c32d4874610ef64c948e6a5c627/kotlinx-coroutines-io-jvm-0.1.8.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-io-jvm/0.1.8/595d4772d0600272bac6a2dcec2646b037285863/kotlinx-io-jvm-0.1.8.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-html-jvm/0.6.12/95dfe9d85947c8dd57c16dced385a37280166e56/kotlinx-html-jvm-0.6.12.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/1.2.1/4d891cee198626c08ac30028afdd743558507ad9/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8-1.2.1.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.2.1/3839faf625f4197acaeceeb6da000f011a2acb49/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.2.1.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.31/11289d20fd95ae219333f3456072be9f081c30cc/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.31.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-http-cio/1.2.0/9dc1ab0d309da3a03b4e4435b9dc52afbc78c580/ktor-http-cio-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-http/1.2.0/c160a65dea5200650efd8db738fa157d8e7c3f8/ktor-http-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-utils/1.2.0/67edd57c63978974769e6ab6792713d9253c1db9/ktor-utils-1.2.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/atomicfu/0.12.6/2840b58706d9ef8df7c8aee2e8b6e1444d09df60/atomicfu-0.12.6.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe/config/1.3.1/2cf7a6cc79732e3bdf1647d7404279900ca63eb0/config-1.3.1.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http2/4.1.24.Final/c0c0d9d20402e4493083447052b59d5680e88b2e/netty-codec-http2-4.1.24.Final.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-alpn-openjdk8-client/9.4.15.v20190215/d46fbf9d9c37f75e621a30bf8a192fe2ade30963/jetty-alpn-openjdk8-client-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.alpn/alpn-api/1.1.3.v20160715/a1bf3a937f91b4c953acd13e8c9552347adc2198/alpn-api-1.1.3.v20160715.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.1/378913dfc3c6c71e7e2a2853eff2c3e8ac27599/logback-core-1.2.1.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/kotlin-css/1.0.0-pre.31-kotlin-1.2.41/c40316f81304348a9983ce15a53c81130b16b36a/kotlin-css-1.0.0-pre.31-kotlin-1.2.41.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-io/0.1.8/ab4c5ab04fe13e78ab0d55d71909b22b6f52f658/kotlinx-coroutines-io-0.1.8.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-common/1.2.1/5806e3dd5e8dff59fec96747795353f3ba2bfd60/kotlinx-coroutines-core-common-1.2.1.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-io/0.1.8/59bcca58d0dae17790c96a775664267ff8492356/kotlinx-io-0.1.8.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.31/20c34a04ea25cb1ef0139598bd67c764562cb170/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.31.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.http2/http2-client/9.4.15.v20190215/dea5744484dbb7e192b6eb061e46d3e53a7edd95/http2-client-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-alpn-java-client/9.4.15.v20190215/9e513ee27c5ea1fa4d97186e46f613b44e3a7795/jetty-alpn-java-client-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/atomicfu-common/0.12.3/b09ed1e1b1a0996e0a3b6c454797d44788a21747/atomicfu-common-0.12.3.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.24.Final/8f20009953b2c7c3d860cef928007bc01aa58ac/netty-codec-http-4.1.24.Final.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-handler/4.1.24.Final/bad56e7da211c5ebe031ae155cb648b1065c7bb6/netty-handler-4.1.24.Final.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.http2/http2-common/9.4.15.v20190215/8983928afb3064fe41b449cabcb827c1024dfba/http2-common-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-alpn-client/9.4.15.v20190215/1b215197407fdf8582711e32b187ce458c6097d9/jetty-alpn-client-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec/4.1.24.Final/290857e5103956bbda11836e33245f2439226b77/netty-codec-4.1.24.Final.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport/4.1.24.Final/d37292c94d3a4cba48d9b6cfb6e8e55282035d0d/netty-transport-4.1.24.Final.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-buffer/4.1.24.Final/e354bed2e60b568307138e403f55ba241c1c16d2/netty-buffer-4.1.24.Final.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.http2/http2-hpack/9.4.15.v20190215/1a2b990e51ea38fb742f7cdec24064c32596edb8/http2-hpack-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-http/9.4.15.v20190215/jetty-http-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.4.15.v20190215/jetty-io-9.4.15.v20190215.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-resolver/4.1.24.Final/dbc1e5b50d31aed883ea3beeb6489e1977d0687f/netty-resolver-4.1.24.Final.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-common/4.1.24.Final/7eeecd7906543214c3c1c984d275d3c6de10b99d/netty-common-4.1.24.Final.jar:/Users/NOTiFY/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-util/9.4.15.v20190215/jetty-util-9.4.15.v20190215.jar com.example.ApplicationKt
2019-05-22 08:08:07.394 [main] TRACE Application - {
    # application.conf @ file:/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/HelloKtorWorld/out/production/resources/application.conf: 6
    "application" : {
        # application.conf @ file:/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/HelloKtorWorld/out/production/resources/application.conf: 7
        "modules" : [
            # application.conf @ file:/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/HelloKtorWorld/out/production/resources/application.conf: 7
            "com.example.ApplicationKt.module"
        ]
    },
    # application.conf @ file:/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/HelloKtorWorld/out/production/resources/application.conf: 2
    "deployment" : {
        # application.conf @ file:/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/HelloKtorWorld/out/production/resources/application.conf: 3
        "port" : 8080
    },
    # Content hidden
    "security" : "***"
}

2019-05-22 08:08:07.885 [main] INFO  Application - No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Module function cannot be found for the fully qualified name 'com.example.ApplicationKt.module'
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.executeModuleFunction(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:367)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$executeModuleFunction(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:33)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1$$special$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:287)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1$$special$$inlined$forEach$lambda$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:33)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:320)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:33)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:286)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:33)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:302)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:284)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:257)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:116)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:22)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngine$DefaultImpls.start$default(ApplicationEngine.kt:56)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:21)
    at com.example.ApplicationKt.main(Application.kt:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any suggestions, besides look at your stack trace it's a:

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Module function cannot be found for the fully qualified name 'com.example.ApplicationKt.module'` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into same issue. Above mentioned suggestion of changing flag value or deleting file, didn't worked for me.

Root cause of problem, observed in application.conf

Before

```
 modules = [ ApplicationKt.module ]
```

After

```
 modules = [ com.exp.ApplicationKt.module ]
```

The full path of Applicationkt.module was changed while relocating files in process of structuring classes by movement[in my case].

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. It because Kotlin compile `Application.kt` to `ApplicationKt.class` (the postfix was added). That's why I need to add `Kt` postfix to my conf.

```
modules = [ me.dehasi.httpapi.ApplicationKt.module ]
```

But the filename is just `Application`, **without** `Kt`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with argument `testing: Boolean = false` in function `Application.module`. It looks like that `io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.executeModuleFunction` **doesn't play well if module has argument(s)**. Or arguments have to be declared somehow in `application.conf` file, but this doesn't make sense since it already has default `false` value. Or we are not building the project correctly.

Just remove the argument from the function, the annotations and delete the `ApplicationTest.kt` from `test` folder and you'll good to go.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. 
   
2019-05-28 10:48:57.361 [main] INFO  Application - No ktor.deployment.watch patterns specified, automatic reload is not active
2019-05-28 10:48:57.705 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @753ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
2019-05-28 10:48:57.965 [main] INFO  Application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080

Answer (score 0):

I came here due to having the exact same error and I'm just trying to learn more about this.

If I remove the parameter to the module, so it looks like this:

```
@Suppress("unused") // Referenced in application.conf
fun Application.module() {
    val client = HttpClient(Apache) {
    }
```

Then it start without any complaints.
Why it works, no idea yet!

Edit:
I used the plugin to setup the project and I'm on java 1.8 (though I don't think it matters here)

Edit 2:

This was how the code was generated for me:

```
@Suppress("unused") // Referenced in application.conf
@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.module(testing: Boolean = false) {
    val client = HttpClient(Apache) {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is another solution besides removing the default argument:

add package name on the top of `Application.kt`, it works for me.

my ktor version is 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I updated my project package but forgot to do the same in **application.conf** file which returned this error.

Please double check this too.

Answer (score 0):

- `fun Application.module()` should not have parameters

---

- And the definition of the module has to have as a prefix your package and **path from source root**.

  `application { modules = [ com.package.app.ApplicationKt.module ] }`